# How to get a higher resolution than the limit

Tags: resolution

I would like to have a higher resolution, but my dell monitor (P2210) only supports up to 1680x1050 60Hz, but I would like to have a resolution that is higher than fullHD, aka. 1920x1200 60Hz.
When ever I do change it (I set it to the max resolution in my AMD settings) to 1920x1200, it triggers the "max resolution is 1680x1050" message (see in the picture), and I need to wait 10 seconds before it changes back to my native resolution.
I also tried changing it with this CRU thing, and I got the same results.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAuCG.jpg)

Comment: If there's a limit, there is a good reason for it. If you find a way to bypass the limit you are likely to damage the hardware. I don't know whether the limit is imposed by your monitor or your graphics card, but you will need to change at least one of them. Check the specifications and find out where the restriction derives from. If you're using Ubuntu or similar, you can use `xrandr` to set any resolution you want, with the screen panning through the virtual monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If you force a resolution the display cannot handle, it may resultin weird graphical glitches and even irreparable damage.

The only way to get a higher resolution is by buying a monitor that supports a higher resolution.

Alternatively, you could use techniques to scale things down, so your desktop will still be 1680x1050 but more content is visible. A side effect will be that things like text becomes harder to read if small.

DPI scaling is one way to do it, but if you have a powerful pc, you could also install a Virtual Machine and use Remote Desktop to connect to it. With Remote Desktop it is possible to set a higher resolution than your screen has and using smart-size it will then scale the screen down to something that allows you to see everything. There obviously will be some performance loss, but more content fits the screen.

That said, the best solution still remains buying a bigger monitor.